# how to print list elements with square brackets in a list - Python I

Tags: python, list, random

I'm new to Python, I'm trying to print an empty list with random int numbers through while loop but I'm not getting the square brackets in the output, here's my code:

```
import random
randlist=[]
i=0
while i in range(0,5):
    c=random.randint(1,100)
    randlist.append(c)
    print(c,end=", ")
    i=i+1
print("")
print("Minimum value:\t",min(randlist))
print("Maximum value:\t",max(randlist))
```

the output looks like this:

```
12,31,43,58,63,
Minimum value= 12
Maximum value 63
```

Comment: print(randlist) ?

Comment: yes, I want to print 'randlist' list but I'm not getting brackets in the output.

Comment: And replace the `while` with a `for` loop please.  Spend some time studying

Comment: "yes, I want to print 'randlist' list" Then you should *print the list*, by passing *the list* to the `print` function. `c` is not the list; it is an element of the list. And then you are doing the loop yourself to print each element separately, and put in the commas. The reason you do not see square brackets this way is because there is nothing in your code that would request the square brackets.

Answer (score 2):

Because you're printing the items 1 at a time, rather than printing the whole list, you'll only get square brackets if you put them there (much like how you're putting the commas there yourself, with `end = ", "`). You can build your list with list comprehension:

```
randlist = [random.randint(1, 100) for i in range(0, 5)]
```

Since `randlist` is a python list object, when you print it you get the square brackets and commas automatically:

```
print(randlist)
[81, 21, 92, 56, 59]
```

Comment: I should also point out as a side note, `range(5)` does the same thing as `range(0, 5)`, since it starts from 0.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new to this language, do random module works only in for loop?

Comment: No you can use random wherever you want. If you're referring to Pynchia's comment, they're just referencing the fact that `for` loops are generally preferred when you know the bounds of the loop before hand, like in this case where we're looping over `range(0, 5)`. `while` loops are a little dangerous, because you can accidentally create an infinite loop if you aren't careful.

Comment: well, that did happen lmao. Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem. You ususally use `while` loops when you're going until some condition is met, but you aren't sure how long it will take. You always need an `if` statement inside the loop to check that condition, and `break` if it is met.